# Combine two arrays with ranges

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to combine two arrays. Each of those arrays has children arrays that define ranges. I would like to combine it such that the new array created reflects the new ranges based on values in the two arrays. Example:

```
//I would like to create a new array based on the ranges in a and b.
var a = [[0, 20], [20, 40], [40, 70]];
var b = [[10, 25], [25, 35]]

//The result reflects the new ranges based on values in both the arrays.
var result = [[0, 10], [10, 20], [20, 25], [25, 35], [35, 40], [40, 70]]
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: Are the ranges guaranteed to be ordered? Also yes, please post what you have attempted.

Comment: Yes. They need to be ordered. I tried doing a switch case statement and it got unwieldy. So that didn't work. I'm trying another approach. I'll post it shortly. Thanks guys

Comment: Your question is not making much sense can you please elaborate little more ? Also Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and MCVE. How do you expect us to help you fix your problem if you don't show us any code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works even when the ranges aren't perfectly ordered and non-overlapping.

1. Combine both lists into one array of arrays
2. Flatten the array of arrays into a simple array of numbers
3. Remove the duplicates from the array (each number except the first and last one is included twice so we need to fix that)
4. Loop over the flattened and de-duplicated array
5. Find the index of the min val then remove that min val from the array
6. Add that min val to a "temp_range" representing the individual range
7. If the length of the "temp_range" is now two we add this to our final array of ranges, then have the temp_range start with that current min val

```js
 

    var a = [[0, 20], [20, 40], [40, 70]];
    var b = [[10, 15], [25, 35]]
    var combined = a.concat(b);
    var flattened = combined.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);
    flattened = flattened.filter(function(item, pos) {
        return flattened.indexOf(item) == pos;
    });
    var final_array = [];
    var temp_range = [];
    var minIdx = null; 
    var minVal = null;
    while (flattened.length){
       minIdx = flattened.indexOf(Math.min(...flattened));
       minVal = flattened.splice(minIdx, 1)[0];
       temp_range.push(minVal);
       if(temp_range.length == 2){
         final_array.push(temp_range);
         temp_range = [minVal];
       }
    }
    console.log(final_array);
```

Comment: This is great. Exactly what I needed. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could collect all values in an object, sort it and build tuples out of it.

```js
var a = [[0, 20], [20, 40], [40, 70]],
    b = [[10, 25], [25, 35]],
    values = Object.create(null),
    result = [];

a.concat(b).forEach(function (a) {
    values[a[0]] = true;
    values[a[1]] = true;
});

Object
    .keys(values)
    .map(Number)
    .sort(function (a, b) {
        return a - b;
    })
    .reduce(function (a, b) {
        result.push([a, b]);
        return b;
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

While I liked the other more functional approach posted, I didn't like the fact that it relied on side effects of where things were defined. Here's a version that improves on that a little.

```js
var a = [[0, 20], [20, 40], [40, 70]];
var b = [[10, 25], [25, 35]];

// Utility function for flattening the input arrays
var flatten = function flatten(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(agg, arr) {
    return agg.concat(Array.isArray(arr) ? flatten(arr) : arr);
  }, []);
};

// Combine everything into a single flat list of numbers
var c = flatten(a.concat(b));

// Create a hash out of the values to get unique endpoints
var d = c.reduce(function(agg, n) {
  agg[n] = true;
  return agg;
}, {});

// Reduce the hash to the ranges
var [_, e] = Object.keys(d).map(Number).reduce(function([last, agg], n) {
  if(last === null) return [n, agg];
  agg.push([last, n]);
  return [n, agg];
}, [null, []]);

console.log(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

A more generic approach firstly flattens the concatenated range lists, secondly goes for a sorted and unique variant of this list of range indices and last generates a list of range tuples from it. Thus it does not depend on any range order and/or is agnostic about range span collisions.

```js
function flatten(list) { // simplified variant
  if (Array.isArray(list)) {
    list = list.reduce(function (collector, elm) {

      return collector.concat(flatten(elm));

    }, []);
  }
  return list;
}

function unique(list) { // simplified variant
  var i = -1, k, len = list.length, type;

  while (++i < len) {
    type = list[i];
    k = i;

    while ((i in list) && (++k < len)) {
      if ((k in list) && (list[k] === type)) {

        list.splice(k, 1);
        --len;
        --k;
      }
    }
  }
  return list;
}

var aRangeList = [[0, 20], [20, 40], [40, 70]];
var bRangeList = [[10, 25], [25, 35]];

var cRangeList = unique(

  flatten(aRangeList.concat(bRangeList)).sort()

).reduce(function collectRangeTuple (collector, rangeIndex) {
  var tuple = collector.recentTuple;

  tuple.push(rangeIndex);

  if (tuple.length >= 2) {
    collector.rangeList.push(tuple);
    collector.recentTuple = [rangeIndex];
  }
  return collector

}, { recentTuple: [], rangeList: [] }).rangeList;

console.log('aRangeList : ', aRangeList);
console.log('bRangeList : ', bRangeList);
console.log('cRangeList : ', cRangeList);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```